# How to extract value (username) from a string (formulaR1C1) to be replaced in over 1000 formulas across the document

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have a document with over 1000 formulas embedded so I'm extracting the Environ("username") and from the R1C1 formula I want to extract the current username on all the formulas from "C:\Users[username]\OneDrive\ and then replace with the new Environ one.

The formula I developed is:

```excel-formula
MID(B3,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B3,"\",CHAR(1),2))+1,FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B3,"\",CHAR(1),3))-FIND(CHAR(1),SUBSTITUTE(B3,"\",CHAR(1),2))-1)
```

B3 Would be:

```vba
Worksheets(1).Range("L2").FormulaR1C1
```

But that formula only works inside Excel, and not in the VBA environment, I tried the evaluate method without success

Here's the code:

```vba
Dim EnvUser As String
EnvUser = Environ("username")

Dim User As String
        
User = Worksheets(1).Range("L2").FormulaR1C1

User = Application.Evaluate("Mid(User, Find(CHAR(1), Substitute(User, " \ ", CHAR(1), 2)) + 1, Find(CHAR(1), Substitute(User, " \ ", CHAR(1), 3)) - Find(CHAR(1), Substitute(User, " \ ", CHAR(1), 2)) - 1)")
MsgBox User
```

Comment: If you have office 365 you can use: `=TEXTBEFORE(TEXTAFTER(B3,"\"),"\")`

Comment: but in your Evaluate you would replace all the `User` with `" & User & "` the variables need to be outside the quotes.

Comment: And `" \ "` need to be `""\""`  Double the quotes to keep them.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, I updated the formula with your feedback:
User = Application.Evaluate("Mid(" & User & ", Find(CHAR(1), Substitute(" & User & ", "" \ "", CHAR(1), 2)) + 1, Find(CHAR(1), Substitute(" & User & ", "" \ "", CHAR(1), 3)) - Find(CHAR(1), Substitute(" & User & ", "" \ "", CHAR(1), 2)) - 1)")
But now: Run-time error '13': Type mismatch

Comment: there is a limit to the number of characters that evaluate can use.  But you do not need to to that with evaluate.  Just use vba: `User = Split(User, "\")(1)`

Comment: @ScottCraner: It's `User = Split(User, "\")(2)`. You want the user name, not `Users`.

Comment: Wouldn't _Data > Edit Links > Change Source_ be easier?

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I went with @ScottCraner solution `User = Split(User,"\")(2)`

Answer (score 0):

Pattern match and replace using a Regular Expression.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub ChgUser()

    Dim regex, f As String
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = False
        .IgnoreCase = True
        .Pattern = "(.*Users\\)([^\\]+)(\\OneDrive.*)"
    End With

    Dim cell As Range, n As Long, NewUser As String
    NewUser = Environ("username")

    For Each cell In Sheets("Sheet1").UsedRange
    
        f = cell.Formula2R1C1 '"C:\Users\username\OneDrive\"
        If regex.Test(f) Then
           f = regex.Replace(f, "$1" & NewUser & "$3")
           'Debug.Print cell.Address, f
           cell.Formula2R1C1 = f
           n = n + 1
        End If
        
    Next
    MsgBox n & " cells updated.", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

### Change User Name in OneDrive Path

```vb
Sub ChangeUser()
    
    Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook ' workbook containg this code
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)
    Dim cell As Range: Set cell = ws.Range("L2")
    
    Dim CellString As String: CellString = cell.FormulaR1C1 ' .Formula
    
    Dim lp As Long: lp = InStr(1, CellString, "C:\Users\", vbTextCompare)
    Dim rp As Long
    rp = InStr(1, CellString, "OneDrive", vbTextCompare) + Len("OneDrive")
    
    Dim OldPath As String: OldPath = Mid(CellString, lp, rp - lp)
    
    MsgBox OldPath

    ' e.g.:
    Dim NewPath As String: NewPath = Environ("OneDrive")
    'ws.UsedRange.Replace OldPath, NewPath, xlPart
    
End Sub
```